# Emulating Django's admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In the Django tutorial they show how to edit 2 related models on a single page here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial07/#adding-related-objects

How can I achieve this in my app? Are there some built-in classes I can use similar to how it works in admin or would I have to create it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the admin's source code, you'll find out it's done using `formsets` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the source code